Why is my approach incorrect (threshold for Dice roll)?

My initial approach to this problem was to fix a threshold $t$, where if your first roll $\leq t$, guess that 2nd roll $>$ first roll, and vice versa. I tried to find the EV of the game as a function of $t$, and then to solve for the value of $t$ that maximizes the EV using the derivative.
The correct approach is to fix a variable for your first roll, and calculate the EV if you guess that 1st roll $\leq$ 2nd roll vs. EV if you guess that 1st roll $>$ 2nd roll.
Why is my initial approach incorrect/inefficient? I'm trying to improve my intuition for how to approach problems of this nature, so any explanation as to why the correct approach works and the initial doesn't are appreciated.
The outline of my initial approach is below:
Assume a threshold t, and that x is 1st roll, y is 2nd roll. Then EV of the game = (average winnings when $x \leq t$) * $P(x \leq t)$ + (average winnings when $x < t$) * $ P(x > t)$.
I tried to calculate $E[winnings | x \leq t]$ using the following:
$\sum_{y=1}^{100} y \cdot P(y > x \mid x \leq t)$
This quickly became complicated.

Other than having a typo in your posted question, I see no reason why your method can't work.  I can not critique your work, because you haven't shown the explicit steps, in excruciating detail, for a reviewer to analyze.
So, a case can be made that this answer is somewhat off point, because I am unable to directly address your question of "where you went wrong".  So, instead, I will detail my attack of the problem, and you can then ask questions.

My approach will be to assume that the first roll is exactly $~t \in \{1,2,\cdots,100\},~$ that the 2nd roll is $~y,~$ and then determine:

$f(t) = ~$ expected payout if you guess $~y < t.~$
$g(t) = ~$ expected payout if you guess $~y > t.~$

Then, I will find the smallest value of $~t~$ such that $~f(t) \geq g(t).~$

Let

$p(t)~$ denote probability 2nd roll smaller.
$q(t)~$ denote probability 2nd roll larger.

So, $~p(t) + q(t) = \dfrac{99}{100}.$
In particular,
$$p(t) = \frac{t-1}{100}, ~q(t) = \frac{100 - t}{100}.$$
Further, if you guess that $~y < t,~$ and this guess is correct, then $~y~$ will be some random element in $~\{1,2,\cdots,t-1\}.~$  Since the payout is linear to $~y,~$ you can assume here that $~y = \dfrac{t}{2}.~$
Therefore,
$$f(t) = \frac{t-1}{100} \times \frac{t}{2}. \tag1 $$

Similarly, if you guess that $~y > t,~$ and this guess is correct, then $~y~$ will be some random element in $~\{t+1, t+2,\cdots,100\}.~$  Again, since the payout is linear to $~y,~$ you can assume here that $~y = \dfrac{101+t}{2}.~$
Therefore,
$$g(t) = \frac{100-t}{100} \times \frac{101+t}{2}. \tag2 $$
Therefore,
$$f(t) \geq g(t) \iff t(t-1) \geq (100-t)(101 + t) \iff $$
$$t^2 - t \geq 10100 - t - t^2 \iff 2t^2 \geq 10100 \iff t^2 \geq 5050.$$
Note that $~71^2 = 5041, ~72^2 = 5184.~$
Consequently, you should guess that the 2nd roll is smaller, if and only if the first roll is $~\geq 72.$

There's nothing wrong with your approach in principle. It's just that, as you said, it becomes complicated to compute the results that approach asks for.
But it's a good question how you might think of a simpler approach to a problem like this.
You already have a good intuition: there's some threshold $t$ such that if $x < t$
(where $x$ is the first roll) you should guess that $y \geq x$
(strategy $G$ for "greater")
and if $x \geq t$ you should guess that $y < x$ (strategy $L$ for "less").
That's because for small $x$, strategy $G$ is better because the expected winnings $W$ when the first roll is $x$ and you guess $y \geq x$
-- let's denote this $E[W \mid x, G]$ -- are greater than if you guess $y < x$, that is,
$$
E[W \mid x, G] > E[W \mid x, L],
$$
but for large $x$, strategy $L$ is better because
$$
E[W \mid x, G] < E[W \mid x, L].
$$
So really you just need to figure out how large $x$ needs to be so that
$E[W \mid x, G] < E[W \mid x, L]$.
You can do this by figuring out $E[W \mid x, G]$ and $E[W \mid x, L]$ in terms of $x$.
